# Проблема с путями до файла

Tags: javascript

Файлы лежат в папке **fixtures**, при выполнении команды: `gendiff __fixtures__/file1.json __fixtures__/file2.json` утилита работает исправно, но когда пытаюсь выполнить `gendiff file1.json file2.json` выскакивает ошибка `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`, вот код из index.js где прописаны пути до файла:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import parse from './parsers.js';
import ast from './format/index.js';
import compare from './build.js';

const getPath = (filename) => path.resolve(process.cwd(), filename);

const getFileFormat = (filename) => path.extname(filename).slice(1);

const readFile = (filepath) => fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8');

const getDiff = (file1, file2, formatName = 'stylish') => {
  const path1 = getPath(file1);
  const data1 = parse(readFile(path1), getFileFormat(file1));

  const path2 = getPath(file2);
  const data2 = parse(readFile(path2), getFileFormat(file2));

  const diff = compare(data1, data2);
  const formattedDiff = ast(diff, formatName);
  return formattedDiff;
};

export default getDiff;
```

Comment: Выхода два: либо вы в консоли так и прописываете `__fixtures__/JSON` либо в `index.js`  дописываете к путям префикс.....

Comment: В целом, проблема не ясна, что не так. Делайте норм путь и будет норм  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Да, если дописать префикс, то команда `gendiff file1.json file2.json` работает, но перестает работать `gendiff __fixtures__/file1.json __fixtures__/file2.json`. По задумке утилита должна работать из любой директории. Вот репозиторий: https://github.com/MrNovan/frontend-project-46.git

Comment: тогда вам нужно завести переменную, которая хранит путь до текущего запускаемого файла и уже оперировать путём относительно него....  то есть к примеру `let  basePath = __DIR__;  let fixturePath = basePath + '../__fixtures'; let filePath = fixturePath + '/' . JSON_FILE`   ...... \_\_DIR__ - это из PHP  если что))  Это чисто для примера